# Big Sur keyboard shortcut to select text

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Before upgrading to Big Sur I was able to use Shift-Command-Left/Right arrow to highlight a single word while typing.  This was in any app - email, browser, text, etc.

After upgrading to Big Sur, that command now changes the color profile.

For what it's worth, Shit-Left/Right arrow will still highlight a single character.  Shift-Command-Left/Right arrow will still highlight the start/end of the line of text.  And Option-Left/Right arrow still moves the cursor one word at a time.

I'm just missing the option to highlight one word at a time.

I know how to add keyboard shortcuts but not sure the best way to change this back?

Comment: Can't think that would have been intentional by Apple; text editing is a pretty basic functionality. If you go into another account, does it have the same behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Testing in **macOS Big Sur** and **macOS Catalina**, the <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>left/right arrow</kbd> *keyboard shortcut* highlights one word at a time.

By default <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>left/right arrow</kbd> highlights from the cursor to the end/beginning of the line.

Comment: Hmm.  So something is changed on mine.  Do you know where I could add that functionality back?

Comment: @Todd, The _keyboard shortcuts_ mentioned in my answer are the default **macOS** built-in _keyboard shortcuts_ for these actions and the only place **macOS** provides a **UI** to change _keyboard shortcuts_ is in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts**.  As far as I can tell there is no settings there to modify these particular built-in defaults. So I'm not sure how you could have modified these defaults unless your did something via command line or a third-party utility, which in either case I do not have any clues for you, sorry.